# Gmail added height in empty td in email signature

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, gmail

I have a problem with an empty td in my clients email signature. It looks fine in Outlook, but when I send an email with the signature from Outlook to Gmail my td adds in height. It's not that big of a deal in the browser version of Gmail, but in the Gmail app the added height is way to much. See the pictures I've included.

[Gmail app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP1Rf.png)

[Gmail browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1DcW.png)

My code:

```
<td bgcolor="#B5987F" style="height:3; width:100%; font-size:0; line-height:3px; mso-line-heightrule:exactly; border-top: 3px solid #ffffff;border-bottom: 3px solid #ffffff;">&nbsp;</td>
```

The white borders are added for extra spacing. When I remove them it makes no difference. When I remove the   Outlook ignores the specified height and adds to the height, but when I send an email with the signature to Gmail the height is looks like it's supposed to be.

I've also experimented with the line-height (also when decreasing both height and line-height to 1(px) the added height gets worse) and font-size, I've put the height and width as attributes instead of inline css, a div inside the td, etc. I'm really stuck as nothing seems to be working.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: did you try with `height: 3px` instead of `height: 3` ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I did try height: 3px which made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `&nbsp;` and try

```
<td bgcolor="#B5987F" style="height:3; width:100%; font-size:0; line-height:3px; mso-line-heightrule:exactly; border-top: 3px solid #ffffff;border-bottom: 3px solid #ffffff;"></td>
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I have already tried this. 

When I remove [&nbsp;]  Outlook then adds extra height. When I send it to Gmail it does work, but my clients obviously wants the signature to look perfect everywhere.

Comment: I think it should be `mso-line-height-rule` (not `mso-line-heightrule`)

Answer (score 0):

If you forward the email from Gmail mobile app (I tested on iOS) to Gmail desktop, and view source, it shows that Gmail is actually adding in double `<br>` tags.
Since there is no reliable way to use CSS other than inline, and these tags don't exist in the source html signature, it looks like Outlook desktop to Gmail mobile app is a combination that cannot be fixed.
It's the only combination that I found unusable, and so I would recommend moving users from Outlook desktop to OWA

Comment: The line breaks may be added during the forward, so not conclusive, but make sure you use a paragraph tag around text, as this will be added retroactively.

Use `<p style="font-size: 13px; line-height: 1!important; color:#000001!important; margin-top: 0.1px; margin-bottom:0.1px; margin-left:0.1px; margin-right:0.1px;">`

The margin settings should fix this.

For a larger organisation, consider using a 3rd party signature service that adds the signature after sending, standardising it for all users on all apps.